# Durandal and partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, durandal, partials

I`have ASP.NET Durandal Application.

I need to make one partial view which would be used many times, I`ve made tried this :

```
define(function () {
    return {
        comments: [],
            $.ajax({                
                url: '#/comments/index/' + id,
                success: function(data) {
                    that.comments = data;
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This code is inside another viwemodel which calls /ViewModels/Comments/Index and passes parameter, but this Comments/Index returns full HTML(With layout).

this is comments route configugration

```
{ route: 'comments/index/:id', moduleId: 'viewmodels/comments/index', nav: false}
```

How i can get comments html without layout?
And is this good approach for partial views?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of searching this resolved my problem

```
<div data-bind=" compose: { model: 'viewmodels/Posts/_index', activate: true, activationData: [2, 100] }"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to return partial view instead of the view , it will pass the view without the layout. Try using,

`return PartialView();` instead of `return View()`

Comment: I`m returning only Json from API controller and then bind it with knockout.

Comment: Where is the index view , don't you have a action method to return it ?

Comment: No it is just html file like other views in Durandal

Comment: May be it's better if you can provide a screenshot of your file structure here.. Then it will be more clear

Comment: Have you ever used Durandal starter kit? I have durandal default structure MVC Project > App > viewmodels, views

Comment: I have created exactly the same thing but, I don't get any layout while access the path `App/views/comments/index.html`.